# Drawing location coordinates on app's page

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

I'm trying to add a feature in my app that goes like this:
I want to get the user's coordinates (from the GPS) and show the user on a blank map, without any street/buildings or any map view, just a blank page, such as the user will be shown at the center of the page and other saved location coordinates will be marked on the page relatively to the user.
For example, if the user is staying at a coordinate <41.40338, 2.17403> and a mark is 5 meters north of him then I want to show the user in the center of the page and the mark will be shown north to him on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google maps. It lets you get the user location plus you could mark saved user locations on the map too. Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker) tutorial.

You can use custom google maps to create a blank map using the maps wizard [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com). I created a blank map by turning the densities of roads, labels and landmarks to zero. Then all you gotta do is go to More Options>All>Geometry and disable it.

This is the json that you could use to create a blank map in your app which I created from the google map styling wizard.

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1d2c4d"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8ec3b9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1a3646"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4b6878"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#64779e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4b6878"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#334e87"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#283d6a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#6f9ba5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3C7680"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#304a7d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#98a5be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2c6675"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#255763"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b0d5ce"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#023e58"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#98a5be"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1d2c4d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#283d6a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3a4762"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#0e1626"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4e6d70"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And here's the sample code. You'll know what this is about when you finish the google map tutorial that I posted up there (first link of this post).

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json);
    googleMap.setMapStyle(style);
}
```

Good luck.